# NSTabView alternatives

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, user-interface

Are there any decent NSTabView alternatives? Preferably open source. Something that looks like the tabs in xcode4 (or any other modern tabbed application), support for drag/drop, close button, etc.

I was very surprised to find out that the SDK doesn't offer any besides the very limited NSTabView and searching for alternatives didn't produce any results. I looked into chromium-tabs but it seems like a bit overkill and complex.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many developers use [`PSMTabBarControl`](http://code.google.com/p/maccode/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Utilities/PSMTabBarControl), which offers drag and drop, close buttons, customisable appearance and the like.

Comment: Thanks. Though it seems very outdated. I see some questions here on SO that it doesn't work with newer versions of Interface Builder. Do you know if it can be used in xcode 4?

Comment: https://github.com/zachwaugh/PSMTabBarControl is a forked version that builds in Xcode 4

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at a simple & clean alternative [here](https://github.com/aaron-elkins/ENTabBarView).

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I will check it out the next time I need tabs in one of my projects. BTW, you may want to submit it to Cocoa Controls (http://www.cocoacontrols.com), seems like a good place for finding OSX/iOS controls.